# How would I remove a letter from a string if it is found with .Contains?

Tags: c#

I would like to be able to:

- Check each character in a string (userInput)
- If second string contains this character, remove it from the string

Therefore: 
Take every character in a string and validate that these characters are all in the second string.

For example, if the second string was: "abcdefg" and the user input was "acf", the code should remove the characters "a" "c" and "f" from "abcdefg", therefore checking that all input values are valid (in the other string). This way, duplicates are accounted for.

The code I have currently:

```
foreach (char letter in userInput)
        {

            if (letters.Contains(letter))
            {
                //Here would be the code for removing the character from the string
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cheater!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
```

string letters = contains 7 letters
string userInput = used to input letters up to 7.

Comment: Have you tried `Replace(string, string)`?

Comment: There are a lot of threads with examples on how to do this. Google is your friend. Check out Regex and as mentioned above you can use Replace.

Comment: I don't understand how I would use this to be able to remove the specific letter it is currently looking at with a blank, as letter is a character and letters is a string.

Comment: You can use `new string(wholeText.Except(removeStr).ToArray());`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
        string str = "abcdef";
        string rem = "acf";

        foreach (char cc in rem)
        {
            str = str.Replace(cc.ToString(), "");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: I've attempted to utilize this in my code however it seems to only remove the first letter that is input, such as if it was acf it would remove a from abcdef, but not c or f.

Comment: Did you try to debug this sample and see what is going on inside the loop?

Comment: Thanks, works great :), just had an issue with my ReadKey making it display once and I didn't press it multiple times to find out that it did infact remove multiple, I just had to continue pressing enter due to the loop of ReadKeys. This was perfect for what I wanted so thank you very much, I really don't think this is a duplicate post due to handling characters and strings rather than two strings.